# Amcharts radar chart

Tags: html, amcharts

Amcharts/HTML amateur here! I am trying to replicate a chart that my coworker made but I can no longer seeing the code:

[image: pic 1]

but I can't get my category field to wrap the text. The labels are too long, I would prefer to make the whole `.jpeg` into a square, not a rectangle. I've tried inserting `"autoWrap": true` as above but I couldn't figure out how to place it properly in HTML. I also tried to insert `\n` but again, couldn't get that to work. Please see my current radar graph and HTML. What am I doing wrong??

[image: pic 2]

```
{
    "type": "radar",
    "categoryField": "Quality",
    "gridAboveGraphs": true,
    "startDuration": 2,
    "fontFamily": "Gill Sans MT",
    "handDrawThickness": 0,
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "graphs": [
        {
            "accessibleLabel": "Vietnam",
            "balloonColor": "#BA0C2F",
            "fillColors": "#BA0C2F",
            "id": "Vietnam",
            "labelAnchor": "middle",
            "labelPosition": "bottom",
            "labelText": "",
            "legendValueText": "",
            "lineColor": "#BA0C2F",
            "negativeFillAlphas": 0.11,
            "negativeFillColors": "#BA0C2F",
            "title": "Vietnam",
            "valueAxis": "ValueAxis-1",
            "valueField": "Vietnam",
            "xAxis": "ValueAxis-1",
            "yAxis": "ValueAxis-1"
        },
        {
            "accessibleLabel": "East Asia and Pacific Average",
            "balloonColor": "#",
            "fillColors": "#002F6C",
            "id": "East Asia and Pacific Average",
            "legendPeriodValueText": "East Asia Pacific",
            "legendValueText": "East Asia Pacific",
            "lineColor": "#002F6C",
            "markerType": "square",
            "negativeFillAlphas": 0,
            "negativeFillColors": "#002F6C",
            "title": "East Asia and Pacific Average",
            "valueField": "East Asia Pacific Average"
        },
        {
            "fillColors": "#8C8985",
            "id": "AmGraph-4",
            "lineColor": "#8C8985",
            "title": "Lower Middle Income Average",
            "valueField": "Lower Middle Income Average"
        },
        {
            "fillColors": "#A7C6ED",
            "id": "AmGraph-5",
            "lineColor": "#A7C6ED",
            "title": "United States",
            "valueField": "United States"
        }
    ],
    "guides": [],
    "valueAxes": [
        {
            "id": "ValueAxis-1",
            "dashLength": 3
        }
    ],
    "allLabels": [],
    "balloon": {},
    "titles": [],
    "dataProvider": [
        {
            "Vietnam": "3.528",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "4.09",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "3.5",
            "United States": "4.85",
            "Quality": "Quality of the Education system"
        },
        {
            "Vietnam": "4.156654705",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "4.4",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "3.72",
            "United States": "4.51",
            "Quality": "Quality of math and science education"
        },
        {
            "Vietnam": "3.337434009",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "3.82",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "2.9",
            "United States": "6.09",
            "Quality": "Quality of Scientific Research Institutions"
        },
        {
            "Vietnam": "3.27048357",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "3.96",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "2.97",
            "United States": "5.85",
            "Quality": "University-Industry Collaboration in R&D"
        },
        {
            "Vietnam": "3.919624581",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "4.29",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "3.72",
            "United States": "5.42",
            "Quality": "Availability of Scientists and Engineers"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why `\n` didn't work for you, but it's working in my snippet below.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "radar",
    "categoryField": "Quality",
    "gridAboveGraphs": true,
    "startDuration": 2,
    "fontFamily": "Gill Sans MT",
    "handDrawThickness": 0,
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "graphs": [
        {
            "accessibleLabel": "Vietnam",
            "balloonColor": "#BA0C2F",
            "fillColors": "#BA0C2F",
            "id": "Vietnam",
            "labelAnchor": "middle",
            "labelPosition": "bottom",
            "labelText": "",
            "legendValueText": "",
            "lineColor": "#BA0C2F",
            "negativeFillAlphas": 0.11,
            "negativeFillColors": "#BA0C2F",
            "title": "Vietnam",
            "valueAxis": "ValueAxis-1",
            "valueField": "Vietnam",
            "xAxis": "ValueAxis-1",
            "yAxis": "ValueAxis-1"
        },
        {
            "accessibleLabel": "East Asia and Pacific Average",
            "balloonColor": "#",
            "fillColors": "#002F6C",
            "id": "East Asia and Pacific Average",
            "legendPeriodValueText": "East Asia Pacific",
            "legendValueText": "East Asia Pacific",
            "lineColor": "#002F6C",
            "markerType": "square",
            "negativeFillAlphas": 0,
            "negativeFillColors": "#002F6C",
            "title": "East Asia and Pacific Average",
            "valueField": "East Asia Pacific Average"
        },
        {
            "fillColors": "#8C8985",
            "id": "AmGraph-4",
            "lineColor": "#8C8985",
            "title": "Lower Middle Income Average",
            "valueField": "Lower Middle Income Average"
        },
        {
            "fillColors": "#A7C6ED",
            "id": "AmGraph-5",
            "lineColor": "#A7C6ED",
            "title": "United States",
            "valueField": "United States"
        }
    ],
    "guides": [],
    "valueAxes": [
        {
            "id": "ValueAxis-1",
            "dashLength": 3,
            "axisTitleOffset": 20
        }
    ],

    "dataProvider": [
        {
            "Vietnam": "3.528",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "4.09",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "3.5",
            "United States": "4.85",
            "Quality": "Quality of the\nEducation system"
        },
        {
            "Vietnam": "4.156654705",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "4.4",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "3.72",
            "United States": "4.51",
            "Quality": "Quality of math and\nscience education\n"
        },
        {
            "Vietnam": "3.337434009",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "3.82",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "2.9",
            "United States": "6.09",
            "Quality": "Quality of Scientific\nResearch Institutions"
        },
        {
            "Vietnam": "3.27048357",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "3.96",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "2.97",
            "United States": "5.85",
            "Quality": "University-Industry\nCollaboration in R&D"
        },
        {
            "Vietnam": "3.919624581",
            "East Asia Pacific Average": "4.29",
            "Lower Middle Income Average": "3.72",
            "United States": "5.42",
            "Quality": "Availability of Scientists\nand Engineers"
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/radar.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Note that the `\n` needs to be in the label value itself. I also added `axisTitleOffset` so that the top label doesn't overlap the maximum value of your axis.